# how to output axios returned data to screen

Tags: reactjs, axios

I am successfully returning data from my axios call on page load.

```
     constructor(props) {
        super(props);
          this.state = {
            myData: []
          }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
    let context= this;
    axios.get('http://localhost:3000/returntestvalues',{
    })
      .then((res) => {
        console.log("Res os: ", res.data)
        context.setState({
          myData: res.data
        });

      })
      console.log("res.data", this.state.myData)
  }
```

As you can see there, I am setting the State to the returned data. Now, I want to output this into a table:

```
  render() {
    return (
<body onload="renderData()">
        <table id="customers">
          <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>Message</th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            {this.state.myData?.length > 0
              ? this.state.myData.map((data, index) => (
                  <tr key={index}>
                    <td>{data.name}</td>
                    <td>{data.email}</td>
                    <td>{data.message}</td>
                  </tr>
                ))
              : "No Data Found"}
          </tr>
        </table>
      </body>
    );
  }
}
```

however, I don't know how to do this through react, I've only ever done it through `ejs`. Can anyone help?

Comment: console.log(res) before setting State

Comment: @TusharShahi please see where I placed my console.log. It is not even showing up in my console for some reason now!

Comment: What does this say ? console.log("Res os: ", res.data). Your second log will be empty only, don't worry. State update is asynchronous.

Comment: Why do you have a `?` after `myData`? `this.state.myData?.length`

Comment: @AdityaParab I am not sure to be honest, this was help from an answer below. Should I try to take it out?

Comment: @TusharShahi so I would log this.state.myData?

Comment: No no. You are doing it correct, but it will not have value at that time. What does this say btw  console.log("Res os: ", res.data) ?

Comment: `?` is `optional chaining` operator in JS... But as you're defined your `myData` with empty array in constructor, you don't really need that `?`. Just remove it.

Comment: @TusharShahi I misspelled Res is, lol. meant to be is instead of os.

Comment: @AdityaParab oh okay. Yes I removed it now. I am not sure what the problem is here. very strange :(

Comment: Your component structure is messed up... `<body onload="renderData()">` This is not how you do it with react...

Comment: Do you have codepen/gist of this code? You need to create a separate component and render it via react dom inside your original body

Comment: @AdityaParab yes, here is the codepen `https://codepen.io/gianlucaas/pen/poPWVLx`

Comment: @developerg1000: You need to do something like this - https://codepen.io/adityaparab/pen/PomJexO

Comment: I couldn't test the working code as you have your server running on localhost:3000

Comment: Take a look at this codesandbox. https://codesandbox.io/s/keen-dan-qthd5?file=/src/Home.js 

Replace the `axios.get` url with your url on local and rest of the settings should be same (only this is you need to change the `data.` property names with your original keys

Comment: @AdityaParab I appreciate your help. Unfortunately, it still returned no data

Comment: Any error on console?

Comment: @AdityaParab no. It literally just returns empty. Its very strange.

Comment: Is your API even returning the data? (check in networks panel in chrome)

Comment: So in returntestvalues which is the call I am making, what do I check, headers, preview, response? Preview and response show empty, so not sure what that means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
render() {
    return (
<body onload="renderData()">
        <table id="customers">
          <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>Message</th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            {this.state.myData?.length > 0
              ? this.state.myData.map((data, index) => (
                  <React.Fragment key={index}>
                    <td>{data.name}</td>
                    <td>{data.email}</td>
                    <td>{data.message}</td>
                  </React.Fragment>
                ))
              : "No Data Found"}
          </tr>
        </table>
      </body>
    );
  }
}
```

Here i am assuming that the keys are name email and message. you can change yours.

Comment: So I like the way this is done. I have a question though. 1) the data has multiple rows of data, so do I not have to loop through them to output all the returned data. 2) I tried your way, and it doesn't actually output anything onto the screen. Am I maybe setting state wrong?

Comment: 1) data has multiple rows of data then you have have a map inside the map that I have written. 

2) the myData state is declared as string it should be array to store the response or keep it undefined.

Comment: oh okay. So I've updated my question to show what I now have based on your answers. On screen now, it is showing No Data Found, so I am assuming that the setState is messed up, because I know for sure that it is returning data, as I see the call beign made through the server side

Comment: console.log("myData",myData) to check value

Comment: yea it is being returned empty. Not sure why!

Comment: hmm okay. I clicked on returntestvalues call, but not sure what to look for. sorry, im new to this lol

Comment: add console for res after then in axios

Answer (score 1):

You can map your received data like below.

```
return (
      
      <body onload="renderData()">
      <table id="customers">
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Email</th>
        <th>Message</th>
      </tr>
{this.state.myData?.length>0 && this.state.myData.map(function(data,index){
return (<tr>
        <td>{data.name}</td>
        <td>{data.email}</td>
        <td>{data.message}</td>
      </tr>);
})}
      

    </table>
    </body>
    );
```

Comment: So I like the way this is done. I have a question though.  I tried your way, and it doesn't actually output anything onto the screen. Am I maybe setting state wrong?

Comment: you can log your state data and if you are getting object instead of object array then it will not print any data.
your data should be like [{name:"john",email:"abc@gmail.com",message:"Hello"},{name:"Doe",email:"bcd@gmail.com",message:"Hello 123"}]

Comment: in my question it shows I am logging state data, but it is returning empty array

Comment: if data is empty then what it will display?

Comment: yes I know, thats why everyone above is trying to help me out to figure out why it is empty. I believe the set state is being messed up somehow. take a look at this `https://codepen.io/gianlucaas/pen/poPWVLx` it is my codepen showing all the code

Comment: Please check https://jsfiddle.net/au0cgfb5/1/ setstate is working direclty in didmount with static data. So I think you have issue with api data. please check there